# Rails flash message is not disappearing

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to apply javascript on my flash message but it is not disappearing .I have tried applying the code on the same page as well as on application.js but the flash message is not dissappearing.
[article_controller.rb]

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

    before_action :set_params,only: [:edit,:update,:show,:destroy]

    def index
        @articles=Article.all
    end

    def new
        @article=Article.new
    end

    def edit
    end

    def create

        @article=Article.new(article_params)
        @article.user=User.first
        if @article.save
            flash[:success]="Article was successfuly created"

        redirect_to article_path(@article)
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def show
    end

    def update
        if @article.update(article_params)
          flash[:success]="Article was successfuly updated"
           redirect_to article_path(@article)
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @article.destroy
        flash[:danger]="Article was successfuly deleted"
        redirect_to articles_path
    end

    private

        def set_params
            @article=Article.find(params[:id])
        end

        def article_params
            params.require(:article).permit(:title,:description)
        end

end
```

[_message.html.erb]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('#flash').remove();
  }, 5000);
 })
</script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">

<% flash.each do |name,msg| %>
    <div class='alert alert-<%="#{name}" %>'>
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&#215;</a>

    <%= content_tag :div,msg, :id=>"flash_#{name}" if msg.is_a?(String) %>
    </div>
<% end %>

    </div>
</div>
```

[application.html.erb]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>BlogApplication</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= render 'layouts/navigation' %>
<%= render 'layouts/messages' %>
<div class="container">
<%= yield %>
</div>
<%= render 'layouts/footer' %>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually what is the problem with flash message appearing on your page ? Do you want to automatically close it using JS rather than clicking on close button of the flash message ?

Comment: yeah i want the flash message should get automatically  dissapear after 3 seconds on my page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u can automatically remove the flash message using jQuery or JS, I will give you a sample code just go through it and make the necessary modifications in your code :)

**Common for all**

```
$(".alert" ).fadeOut(3000);
```

**For alert success:**

```
 $(".alert-success" ).fadeOut(3000);
```

**For alert danger:**

```
$(".alert-danger" ).fadeOut(3000);
```

Comment: @aniket : Ok just let me know if it worked or not :)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing seems to have the #flash id you're trying to remove:

```
 $('#flash').remove();
```

You'll probably need:

```
 $('.flash').remove();
 <%= content_tag :div,msg, :class => 'flash', ...
```

Or better yet, something around that since there's a

```
<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&#215;</a>
```

above